# How can I access both ports 8080 and 9990 on bluemix single container for wildfly?

Tags: docker, port, containers, wildfly, ibm-cloud

I'm trying to run a Wildfly image on a Bluemix single container and I need to access both ports 9990 (default admin) and 8080 (deafault public); the problem is I can only get access to 8080.

So far I've build a simple docker image from the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM jboss/wildfly-camel

RUN /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/add-user.sh admin password

EXPOSE 8080 9990

CMD ["/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-bmanagement", "0.0.0.0"]
```

Locally everything works just fine if I run:

```
docker run -it -p 8080:8080 -p 9990:9990 myimage:tag
```

On Bluemix container I'm not able to access to port 9990 even if it does result mapped from `cf ic ps -a`:
[image]

I've got the same error creating container either by CLI or Web GUI.
Is there something I'm doing wrong?

**2016 Feb 05 : UPDATE : the port 9990 is now available.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IBM Bluemix containers whitelist the ports that can be exposed and 9990 is not on the list.

You can try use an alternative port (like 9090 for example) or open a ticket with Bluemix support team and request port 9990 to be opened:

http://ibm.biz/bluemixsupport

PS: For security reasons the list of open ports are not externally documented.